# Проблема с центрированием картинки во splash screen при использовании Launcher Theme

Tags: android

Для splash screen использую Launcher Theme. Реализацию брала из этой [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/345380/) (первый пример). SplashActivity не используется. Проблема в том, что на разных экранах картинка или сжата или растянута.  Пробовала в стилях прописать scaleType="centerCrop" - никаких изменений. Как можно сделать чтобы картинка располагалась по центру на разных экранах, а лишнее обрезалось?

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<!-- сплэш -->

<style name="Default_theme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>

</style>
```

Где `background_splash` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/badge_c"/>
</item>
```